# Why does dijit/registry's byId() method "not exist"?

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to use [digit/registry](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#) to get the object for a digit so I can read/change its proprerties. But for some reason I get a JavaScript error that no "byId" method exists for the registry object in the (trimmed-down) code below:

```
define(["dojo/dom-style", "dijit/registry", [...] ],
        function(domStyle, registry, [...])
{
    var self =
    {
        moveSplitter: function(datasetsLength)
        {   
             var myBC = registry.byId("studiesBorderContainer");    
        },
    }
}
```

I seem to be able to duplicate this problem in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rUNNr/2/

Yet it works on the [Dojo documentation page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#) (see the example at the very bottom of the page... compare first line of output when you click Run with that on the JSFiddle.)

What am I missing? (Note: it's also possible I didn't set up the JSFiddle correctly for a dojo example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple other posters found a problem with my jsFiddle, but not the answer to my original question. I found the answer myself just now, so I'm sharing in case anyone else has a similar issue.

The original question was the registry.byId() call was returning "no method exists". The answer is that you (apparently) can't get access to "dijit/registry" from your define([...],function(...)] block, but instead must use require(). I formerly did not understand the difference between define() and require(), so I read up on this which was helpful:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules/

In short, define() defines a module, but you can still use require() blocks *inside* your defined module to get access to certain things that apparently require it. I still don't understand this fully (i.e. why "digit/registry" doesn't work when added to the define block) but for whatever reason this fixed my problem. SO my code now looks more like this:

```
define(["dojo/dom-style", [...] ],
        function(domStyle, [...])
{
    var self =
    {
        moveSplitter: function(datasetsLength)
        {   
            require(["dijit/registry"],
            function(registry)
            {
                var myBC = registry.byId("studiesBorderContainer"); 
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Compare with code in my original question to see the difference. And now it works.

Answer (score 3):

It appears (at least in the Fiddle you linked to), that you are never actually creating the dijit by calling `parser.parse()`.

I [added](http://jsfiddle.net/rUNNr/3/) the call to `parser.parse` as the first line in your `ready` callback, and got back a valid dijit Id from `registry.byId()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`registry.byId()`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#registry-byid) documentation provides insight into this:

> ... it only works on parsed dijits either declared in markup with a data-dojo-type attribute or programmatically. The same id attribute is used as a parameter, but what is returned in this case is an object that was created by the dojo widget system when the markup is parsed and transformed into a dijit.

So in your example, this behavior makes sense:

- The first case is that the div with ID "textNode3" is not an actual Dojo widget, and so it would not recognized by Dojo's registry module.
- The second case is that while you're provided a data-dojo-type attribute to the input of ID "myTextBox3", Dojo still hasn't actually parsed any of the markup yet. You'll notice in the last example on the [reference guide for registry](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#comparing-dom-byid-and-registry-byid) that they call to the parser module to actually interpret the markup provided.

Adding this line to your Fiddle made the example work as intended.

Comment: Giving this an upvote since it's helpful in getting my jsfiddle example working, but the original question was why registry.byId() retured a "no method exists" error in JavaScript... which apparently my jsFiddle failed to demonstrate once fixed (making it irrelevant to this post unfortunately). However I did find the answer, which I've posted below.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. Glad you found the answer you needed.